# Path to export files in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

what is the best path to export file from Ax 2012 that developer could be sure that everyone have privilege to write and read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar suggestion to Jan's answer...  I think I prefer Matej's suggestion if it's just a 'random' file that you are writing

```
FileIOPermission    _permHACK = new FileIOPermission('','r');
str                 tempPath;                           
;
_permHACK.assert();
tempPath = (isRunningOnServer() ? 
    WinAPIServer::getTempPath() :WinAPI::getTempPath());
CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, what about the folder returned by [getTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/winapiserver.gettemppath.aspx)?

It should be writable by everyone (no guaranties) but there is one for every user!

If you want a shared folder, you should ask the domain admin of your server.

Comment: Your link poins to `WinAPIServer::getTempPath` which returns temp path on server (and therefore not accessible to client).

Comment: Then look in WinAPI class for similar function. If not found copy yourself and replace server keyword with client.

Comment: I would use getTempPath as a fallback but parameterise depending on the function, your SU/SysAdmin may wish you to use dedicated fileserver rather than the client location

Answer (score 1):

Use [`WinAPI::getTempFilename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/winapi.gettempfilename(AX.60).aspx) which creates temporay file on the *client*.
Use returned filename for temporary data.